# Is it okay that part of the power jack is outside the device?

Tags: power-supply, power, adapter, charger, power-jack

I have some devices whose DC adapter connector/jack is only partially plugged in.

For example, my monitor has an AC to 180 W DC power supply. When connecting the transformer to the monitor, the DC adapter connector/jack is not fully inside the monitor.

Is this faulty product or is it okay that part of the power jack is outside the device?

[image: Image about the part that sticking out]

Comment: What _voltage_ is said power supply? From a safety standpoint it's typically fine as barrel-jack connectors tend to be low voltage; it can be a warning sign that you mixed up and grabbed the wrong power supply.

Comment: From a safety standpoint, barrel-jacks typically have the ground on the outside (by convention). Typically we only use barrel-jacks for DC, which means that the exposed metal is likely connected to ground.

Comment: I am not asking for safety standpoint. I am asking if it affects my monitor/device in any way.

Comment: It's slightly hard to define, but if all contacts are contacting, (as opposed to "just touching") then that is fine. On many connectors, there is a bit of a gap like the one you show, so that the plastic shield of the plug doesn't foul the casing of other devices, which may not have so much clearance - take a look at the next-but-one connector below, for example, which is deeper within the casing.

Comment: @Aron Unless it's a Sony device. For some reason Sony's always gone center-negative.

Comment: @Aron As a general rule, the negative output of a standard AC "wall wart" or similar adapter is isolated, not grounded. In fact, many such adapters don't even have grounded plugs, so they couldn't possibly connect to AC ground.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

That's fine, and within normal tolerances. Some sockets will be deeper than others, so cable manufacturers leave themselves a bit of extra length on the plug to ensure maximum compatibility. There aren't many connections that are gapless. Just look at a HDMI cable, USB cable, RCA cable... they all have a small gap where you can see the connector housing.

The are some exceptions of course, such as high voltage (mains) plugs & sockets, or items which need to be concerned with dust and water ingress.

Comment: There are different standard lengths for some diameters, and it's reasonable to buy in power supplies with a long plug for use with kit that's built with a shorter socket.  The other way round isn't necessarily secure. But with a good match (shape, not just length) the gap can be too small to slide in a piece of paper.

Comment: One pet peeve of a professor of mine was the IBM PC's serial port, a *male* connector exposing all pins to the casual observer!

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: That's not so bad as the "Atari"-style joystick ports, which often have connections direct the the power and ground rails.  Shorting arbitrary combinations of pins on a serial port would be harmless, but that is not true of Atari-style joysticks.